# JAXB anyType fails to cast

Tags: java, xml, soap, jaxb

The following code is resulting in a cast exception and I'm not sure why. Objects in ParameterValueList should be eagerly unmarshalled to the JAXB object ParameterValueStruct, but it's not. Everything was generated directly from the soap encoding and cwmp schema files.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException, FileNotFoundException 
{
    JAXBContext c = JAXBContext.newInstance("org.dslforum.cwmp_1_1");

    Unmarshaller u = c.createUnmarshaller();
    Inform inform = (Inform) u.unmarshal(new FileInputStream("test.xml"));

    List<Object> list = inform.getParameterList().getAny();
    System.out.println(list); // prints [[ParameterValueStruct: null], ...

    for (Object o : list) {
        ParameterValueStruct pv = (ParameterValueStruct)o; // exception here
        System.out.println(pv.getName());
    }
}
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementNSImpl cannot be cast to org.dslforum.cwmp_1_1.ParameterValueStruct
>       at Test.main(Test.java:26)

I have this class which was generated from http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/ using Java's xjc tool:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Array", propOrder = {
    "any"
})
@XmlSeeAlso({
    ParameterValueList.class,
})
public class Array {

    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    protected List<Object> any;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "id")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CollapsedStringAdapter.class)
    @XmlID
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "ID")
    protected java.lang.String id;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "href")
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "anyURI")
    protected java.lang.String href;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "arrayType", namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/")
    protected java.lang.String arrayType;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "offset", namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/")
    protected java.lang.String offset;
    @XmlAnyAttribute
    private Map<QName, java.lang.String> otherAttributes = new HashMap<QName, java.lang.String>();

    public List<Object> getAny() {
        if (any == null) {
            any = new ArrayList<Object>();
        }
        return this.any;
    }
    ....
}
```

I also have these 2 classes which were also generated via the same tool, but from https://www.broadband-forum.org/cwmp/cwmp-1-1.xsd:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "ParameterValueList")
public class ParameterValueList
    extends Array
{
}
```

Second file:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "ParameterValueStruct", propOrder = {
    "name",
    "value"
})
public class ParameterValueStruct { 
    @XmlElement(name = "Name", required = true)
    protected String name;
    @XmlElement(name = "Value", required = true)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "anySimpleType")
    protected Object value;
    ...
}
```

And here is my test.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<cwmp:Inform xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:soap-enc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:cwmp="urn:dslforum-org:cwmp-1-1" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ParameterList soap-enc:arrayType="cwmp:ParameterValueStruct[3]">
    <ParameterValueStruct>
      <Name>Device.DHCPv4.ClientNumberOfEntries</Name>
      <Value xsi:type="xsd:unsignedInt">0</Value>
    </ParameterValueStruct>
    <ParameterValueStruct>
      <Name>Device.DNS.Client.ServerNumberOfEntries</Name>
      <Value xsi:type="xsd:unsignedInt">1</Value>
    </ParameterValueStruct>
    <ParameterValueStruct>
      <Name>Device.DeviceInfo.AdditionalSoftwareVersion</Name>
      <Value xsi:type="xsd:string">DM: 532,SK: 2.6.33.9-rt31,SF: 251X 137.0,BK: 10</Value>
    </ParameterValueStruct>
  </ParameterList>
</cwmp:Inform>
```

Answer (score 4):

You just have to add `@XmlRootElement(name="ParameterValueStruct",namespace="")` in front of `ParameterValueStruct`

Here you need explicit `namespace=""` becauce of the  `package-info.java`

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "urn:dslforum-org:cwmp-1-1")
package org.dslforum.cwmp_1_1;
```

T**he correct class should look like this:**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "ParameterValueStruct", propOrder = {
    "name",
    "value"
})
@XmlRootElement(name="ParameterValueStruct",namespace="")
public class ParameterValueStruct { 
    @XmlElement(name = "Name", required = true)
    protected String name;
    @XmlElement(name = "Value", required = true)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "anySimpleType")
    protected Object value;
    ...
}
```

PS: See this http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/12/jaxbs-xmlanyelementlaxtrue-explained.html for a better JAXB-tutorial about `@XmlAnyElement(lax=true)`

Comment: Had to add namespace = "" to your suggestion to get it to work. In total: @XmlRootElement( name = "ParameterValueStruct", namespace = "" )

Comment: @ComputerEngineer88 I have missed the package-info.java which sets the namespace for all classes, here is the updated answer.

Comment: I'm still not sure why I needed to specify an empty namespace. Is there any way to do this such that ParameterValueStruct would be castable like the other classes in the package? Ie not having to specify an empty namespace?

Comment: I'm no sure what's the reason for it but it must be `ParameterValueList extends Array`. You could change ParameterValueList not to extend Array and has it's own fields.